# How to provide for 2 different IP ranges? --pod-network-cidr= for multiple IP ranges

Tags: kubernetes, ip, kubeadm, cidr

I have 2 different IP sets in the same network. My kubeadm is in a different IP range than my other nodes. How shall I set the property here: `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=`

```
cat /etc/hosts
#kubernetes slaves  ebdp-ch2-d587p.sys.***.net 172.26.0.194,  ebdp-ch2-d588p.sys.***.net 172.26.0.195
10.248.43.214 kubemaster
172.26.0.194 kube2
172.26.0.195 kube3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--pod-network-cidr` is for IPs of the pods that kubernetes will manage. It is not related with nodes of the cluster.

For nodes, the requirement is ([from Kubernetes doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/)):

> Full network connectivity between all machines in the cluster (public
>   or private network is fine)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Yavuz Sert answer, `--pod-network-cidr` flag identifies Container Network Interface ([CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network)) IP pool for Pods communication purpose within a Kubernetes cluster. You have to choose some separate IP subnet for Pod networking, it has to be different against your current given network sets. Since `--pod-network-cidr` has successfully applied [kube-proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/) reflects Pod IP subnet and add appropriate routes for network communication between Pods through cluster overlay network. Indeed you can find `clusterCIDR` flag withing kube-proxy configmap which corresponds to `--pod-network-cidr`.